# ActiveAdmin with CanCanAdapter causing infinite redirect on dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin, cancan

When using the CanCan adapter in ActiveAdmin 0.6.0. I have a resource working and authorization is working. However, when I go to `/admin`, the root ActiveAdmin page, it redirects to `/admin` and continues this forever.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the user does not have access to a page, ActiveAdmin redirects to the Dashboard. If the user doesn't have access to the dashboard, this results in an infinite redirect.

Solution is to give the user the ability to read the dashboard page. Place this in the ability model object:

```
can :read, ActiveAdmin::Page, :name => "Dashboard"
```

This is mentioned in the [authorization adapter documentation](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/docs/13-authorization-adapter.md#using-the-cancan-adapter), but the infinite redirect seems to be caused by a bug in ActiveAdmin. It is neither raising a CanCan::AccessDenied, nor displaying an message to the user. At the least, it should display a message in development to help troubleshoot this issue. But it does not currently.

Comment: Looks like you'll be issuing an AA pull request.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `config.on_unauthorized_access` config option as described [here](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/docs/13-authorization-adapter.md).

```
# You can also specify a method to be called on unauthorized
# access. This is necessary in order to prevent a redirect
# loop that can happen if a user tries to access a page they
# don't have permissions for
# (see [#2081](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2081)).
config.on_unauthorized_access = :render_403
```

> The method `access_denied` would be defined in `application_controller.rb`. Here is one example that redirects the user from the page they don't have permission to access to a resource they have permission to access (organizations in this case), and also displays the error message in the browser:
>
> class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
>
> ```
>  def access_denied(exception)
>    redirect_to admin_organizations_path, :alert => exception.message
>  end
> ```
>
> end

Comment: This is the correct solution. Unfortunately, the Wiki doesn't seem to mention it any more. It works in ActiveAdmin 0.6.0

Comment: I created pull request to put this into active_admin.rb initializer. Comment +1 if you think it should be included there. Here's the link: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/pull/2471

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, and I have an admin user with:

```
if user.admin?
  can :manage, :all
end
```

I just forgot to add the correct role to this user, so maybe someone will have the same infinite redirect loop as me with ActiveAdmin and Cancan.